# how to draw by mouse an interactive fixed grid within a gui or figure? /python / matplotlib / pyqt5

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below code allows me to draw an interactive rectangle and control its size and location by mouse.

In the same way, how do I draw a fixed interactive grid mXn (see the image at the link below) instead of a rectangle?

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))


def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)


fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()                 # make a new plotting range
N = 100000                                       # If N is large one can see
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N)                    # improvement by use blitting!

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

[image of the mXn fixed grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2MB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, m and n are constants. If not, you can set them high enough. Matplotlib is designed for plotting functions, so PyQt5 is probably a much better choice (especially if you extend the functionality further).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        title = "Grid"
        top = 400
        left = 400
        width = 800
        height = 600

        self.m = 8
        self.n = 6
        self.x1 = 0
        self.x2 = 0
        self.y1 = 0
        self.y2 = 0
        self.st_x = 0
        self.st_y = 0

        self.mode = "draw"

        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(top, left, width, height)

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32) # creating canvas
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.x1 < event.x() < self.x2 and self.y1 < event.y() < self.y2:
            # mouse pressed in grid area
            self.mode = "move"
            self.st_x = event.x()
            self.st_y = event.y()

        else:
            self.mode = "draw"
            self.x1 = event.x()
            self.y1 = event.y()
        
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.update()
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.mode == "draw":
            self.x2 = event.x()
            self.y2 = event.y()
        
        else:
            x_delta = event.x() - self.st_x # 'delta' would be a x, y vector drawn by mouse press and release
            y_delta = event.y() - self.st_y

            self.x1 += x_delta
            self.y1 += y_delta
            self.x2 += x_delta
            self.y2 += y_delta

        self.draw_grid((self.x1, self.y1), (self.x2, self.y2), 50, 50)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
        canvasPainter.drawImage(
            self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect()
        )
         
    def draw_grid(self, start, end, rect_width, rect_height):
        painter = QPainter(self.image)
        painter.setPen(
            QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin)
        )
        
        for y in range(self.n):
            for x in range(self.m):
                if start[0] + rect_width*x < end[0] and start[1] + rect_height*y < end[1]:
                    painter.drawRect(
                        QRect(start[0] + rect_width*x, start[1] + rect_height*y, rect_width, rect_height)
                    )

        self.update()
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec()) # may want to remove sys.exit
```

**Update:** In your example, a `QGraphicsScene` is used, unlike here. I don't know if this object provides any advantage but if you want to see the grid moving, while you are holding the mouse button, you can easily override the [`mouseMoveEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html?highlight=qwidget#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget.mouseMoveEvent), like in the example. `QMainWindow` inherits this event from `QWidget`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! After I draw, How can I move the grid to another position as in the tutorial in the following  [link](https://learndataanalysis.org/drag-and-move-an-object-with-your-mouse-pyqt5-tutorial/)?